# How to control Spotify queue / playlist from a 2nd device

Tags: spotify

I like to leave my iPad on top of my Stereo and then wander around the house. Usually, a song comes to mind and I'd like to add it to the queue or active playlist. Maybe I'm working on my PC and don't want to get up and interrupt what I'm doing, or I'm cooking and I only have my android phone at hand. Sometimes a cool song starts playing and I want to know the artist / album / song name. Has this happened to you?

If I try logging in from a 2nd device, the 1st device (the one playing the music) automatically stops playing and kills the user session.

Is there any kind of "remote control" for Spotify? A hack / plug-in / complementary app is OK.

Answer (score 0):

There have been a number of (OS- or device-dependent) solutions to remote-control Spotify devices, which is nicely summarized on [this website](http://evolver.fm/2012/08/06/how-to-remote-control-spotify-from-iphone-or-android-on-mac-windows-or-even-another-phone/).

But meanwhile, there is the [Spotify Connect](https://www.spotify.com/connect/) functionality available directly from Spotify, which should be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can use just a multimedia remote app. If you want a nice little app with a few more functions you could use Roccat Power-Grid(there are a lot of other apps with the same functions but i dont know if they work or if they are secure). Within the app you can set some grids(you need to configure it through your desktop app) which can be downloaded from the official Roccat page. (http://roccat.org)